# Running and Exporting Numerous Cross-Correlations of Time Series Using CCF() in R

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

I'm looking to find a way to run a cross-correlation between numerous time series stored in one ts object in R and then have that exported properly to a csv/xlsx file.

Right now I have a TS object with ~80 variables (each variable representing different macroeconomic indicators) and 98 rows (each row representing 1 month starting from 2010 going to 2019). These variables are going to be compared to the last variable in the TS (the rightmost column) using ccf() and then if this works, written to a csv/xlsx or any other file which I can manipulate in excel.

Ideally, it would run like:

```
ccf1 = ccf(as.numeric(mvarsTS$`GDP`), as.numeric(mvarsTS$`securitiesbalance`), lag = 4)
```

Except it would iterate through each variable instead of just GDP.

Does anyone know of a way that I can do this?

EDIT:

Here's what I have so far:

```
for(i in names(mvarsTS)) {
ccf1 = ccf(as.numeric(mvarsTS[[i]]), as.numeric(mvarsTS$`SecuritiesBalance`), lag = 4)
acd <- data.frame(cbind(lag=ccf1$lag,acf=ccf1$acf)) 
}
```

Except when I run this I get subscript out of bounds.

If there is a way to run this loop properly and then append the results into the dataframe it would fix my problem

Comment: It is very hard to grasp idea of your question. What is exactly the problem you are facing? Can you restructure your question, please?

Answer (score 0):

This will give a list of `choose(ncol(mtcars), 2)` components:

```
out <- combn(mtcars, 2, function(x) ccf(x[, 1], x[, 2], plot = FALSE)$acf, 
  simplify = FALSE)
names(out) <- combn(names(mtcars), 2, toString)
```